# string.matches(".*") returns false

Tags: java, regex

In my program, I have a string (obtained from an external library) which doesn't match any regular expression.

```
String content = // extract text from PDF
assertTrue(content.matches(".*")); // fails
assertTrue(content.contains("S P E C I A L")); // passes
assertTrue(content.matches("S P E C I A L")); // fails
```

Any idea what might be wrong? When I print `content` to stdout, it looks ok.

Here is the code for extracting text from the PDF (I am using iText 5.0.1):

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(source);
PdfTextExtractor extractor = new PdfTextExtractor(reader,
    new SimpleTextExtractingPdfContentRenderListener());
return extractor.getTextFromPage(1);
```

Comment: marked as favourite as it's not the first time I've been hit by such java bomb.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

By default, the `.` does not match line breaks. So my guess is that your `content` contains a line break.

Also note that `matches` will match the entire string, not just a part of it: it does not do what `contains` does!

Some examples:

```
String s = "foo\nbar";
System.out.println(s.matches(".*"));       // false
System.out.println(s.matches("foo"));      // false
System.out.println(s.matches("foo\nbar")); // true
System.out.println(s.matches("(?s).*"));   // true
```

The `(?s)` in the last example will cause the `.` to match line breaks as well. So `(?s).*` will match any string.

Comment: You saved my day :) I didn't realize that matches() wants to match the entire string.

Comment: @Miroslav, yes, the mistake is easily made since many languages "look" for a match instead of matching the entire string. Good to hear you resolved it!