# Why does a String returned from a HashMap not match although it is identical to System.out?

Tags: java, string, match

Followup to [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396834/string-matches-returns-false).

The aim is to match a String, which is returned by the following method:

```
public String getAssignment() {
    return (String) hashmap.get("assignment");
}
```

**Attempt**

As the following:

```
String s = "12345";
System.out.println(s.matches("12345"));
```

results in a match, the idea was that:

```
System.out.println(assignment.getAssignment());
System.out.println(assignment.getAssignment().length());
System.out.println(assignment.getAssignment().matches("11111"));
System.out.println(assignment.getAssignment().equals("11111"));
System.out.println(assignment.getAssignment().trim().length());
```

should return `true` as well.

**Result**

```
System.out 11111
System.out 15
System.out false
System.out false
System.out 13
```

Comment: Working for me. Could you do a reproductible example?

Comment: @aruisdante Yes, `11111` is returned according System.out

Comment: Most probably the return value of `assignment.getAssignment()` contains some `whitespace` that is not visible in `sout` but makes the string does not match `11111` without these whitespaces. Use a debugger and inspect the return value of `assignment.getAssignment()` or check String's `length`.

Comment: @user2336315 Should I include the HashMap?

Comment: @FabianBarney I will check the String.

Comment: @FabianBarney `System.out.println(assignment.getAssignment().matches("1 1 1 1 1 "));` does not work either

Comment: @FabianBarney Good suggestion. I will check the length of the String.

Comment: @utrecht Uhrm, that's not what I meant when I talked about whitespace before.

Comment: If you just want to check that a value is *equal* to some constant, use `.equals()`. `.matches()` is for regex matching, which is unnecessary for checking against simple String literals.

Comment: @utrecht You may want to inspect the byte array resulting for the String. There might be non printable characters as well.

Comment: Your title is meaningless. A string can't match System.out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, you have "invisible" characters (whitespace) after the value - call `trim()` on the value before testing it.

Also, your check doesn't need regex, so just use `.equals()` instead of `.matches()`.

Try this:

```
assignment.getAssignment().trim().equals("11111")
```

#### Edit

You seem to have *embedded* whitespace - no problem. To remove *all* whitespace from anywhere in the value, use `replaceAll()` (for regex-based replacement):

```
assignment.getAssignment().replaceAll("\\s", "").equals("11111")
```

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer. The length of the string has been reduced from 15 to 13 characters using trim. The expectation was that `trim` would result in 5 characters. I will continue to debug the string.

Comment: @utrecht If you want some tips on what could have happened to it, you can use the following monstrosity to print it out in unambiguous base64 that anyone can look at without losing information:  `System.out.println(javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(assignment.getAssignment().getBytes(java.nio.charset.Charset.forName("UTF-8"))));`

Comment: Or something simpler that will give you the character codes: `for ( char ch : assignment.getAssignment().toCharArray() ) System.out.printf("%x%n",(int)ch);`

Comment: @RealSkeptic the result is: `9`

Comment: @RealSkeptic I am lost. When I run the code the output is: `11111`, `31`, `9`, `9`, `31`, `9`, `9`, `31`, `9`, `9`, `31`, `9`, `9`, `31`, `9`, `9`

Comment: You seem to have two *tab* characters following each of your *1*'s. I have no idea why the output is not showing them widely tabbed, but that's certainly "1\t\t1\t\t1\t\t1\t\t1\t\t" and not "11111".

Comment: @Bohemian Thank you. I will try this solution this evening and I will let you know the outcome.