# Jenkins Pipeline script to email build console o/p in HTML format

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to email the console o/p in HTML format using pipeline script. However, it doesn't seem to be working. Any suggestions.

```
    def notifySuccessful() {
emailext (
      subject: "STARTED: Job ${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]",
      body: '<pre>${BUILD_LOG_EXCERPT, start="^Hello World", end="^Finished: SUCCESS"} </pre>',
    to: 'myemail.com'
    )
    }
```

When I run this, I get the email with the below text in the body

```
${BUILD_LOG_EXCERPT, start="^Hello World", end="^Finished: SUCCESS"}
```

.

I tried with putting ''' or """" or ' to the line

```
${BUILD_LOG_EXCERPT, start="^Hello World", end="^Finished: SUCCESS"}
```

but that doesn't work either. If I enclosed with a single `"`, I get an error that says

> unexpected token BUILD_LOG_EXCERPT

Answer (score 2):

Here you are [prudviraj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3759764/prudviraj)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35357136/8447238), which explains clearly how BUILD_LOG_EXCERPT regex works.

Here you are my email-ext code

```
emailext (
            mimeType: "text/html",
            to: "your_email",
            subject: "Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]'",
            body:'''<html>Build ! 
                    <br />
                    Check console output at <a href="$BUILD_URL">${JOB_NAME} [${BUILD_NUMBER}]</a> 
                    <br /> 
                    <br />
                    <pre>${BUILD_LOG_EXCERPT, start="Started by user Admin user", end="test"}</pre></html>'''
        )
```

The console output

[image]

And the email received

[image]

Comment: I think I am using the same as code but it doesn't seem to work. Please see the code snippet above.

Comment: I am using the same code with ''', the only difference with your code is I defined the body in another variable before using it in the emailext.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your code snippet? I tried it in several ways and all I get is the text <pre>${BUILD_LOG_EXCERPT, start="^Hello World", end="^Finished: SUCCESS"} </pre> in the o/p but not in html converted format

Comment: This is what I get in the console o/p. So it looks like it is not expanding the token Proceeding
[Pipeline] emailext
Job type does not allow token replacement.
Job type does not allow token replacement.
Job type does not allow token replacement.
Job type does not allow token replacement.
Sending email to:

Comment: I added a code example  to my answer. I really don't know why your are not able to replace the token, pay attention to the regex for start and end ([java.util.regex.Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)).

Comment: Thanks much @Lesly. Much appreciated. For some reason, my code still doesn't work and I am beginning to wonder if the version of the plugin is playing any tricks.. I will keep posted.

Comment: I can't get this working no matter how/what I tried. It doesn't interpret the REGEX and prints the command text only. I am using 2.47 version if that has any bugs.